# Membership provider in ASP.Net Core app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-membership

I am enforcing the problem to add membership provider into config in the ASP.Net Core application. I must add it because it references to older projects which contain the legacy code and reference to an assembly of `System.Web.ApplicationServices`. And in this assembly, the flow goes to line, which checks if the name of the provider is not null.

```
if ( providerName == null || SystemWebProxy.Membership.Providers[providerName] == null )
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, ApplicationServicesStrings.Membership_provider_name_invalid), "providerName" );
        }
```

But anyway, I am adding the necessary implementation in `appsettings.json`:

```
"Membership": {
"DefaultProvider": "blahblah",
"Providers": {
  "Add": {
    ...
    "Name": "blahblah"
    ...
  }
}}
```

And in the startup class I am configuring the `sqlMembershipProvider` in the following way:

```
services.Configure<System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider>(Configuration.GetSection("Membership"));
```

Could somebody tell me, why I am not getting my provider implemented into the configuration? Maybe I am going the wrong way?

Comment: Configure<> adds IOption<> interface to DI, which is injected to other classes. To initialise SqlMembershipProvider you need to create it by Add Transient, Scope or Singleton dependency eg. AddTransient<SqlMembershipProvider>() (I don't know a constructor of the class but you might need to initialise it by hand with AddTransient(x=>new SqlMembershipProvider(...)). Or you can wrap the class and inject IOption<MembershipSettings> to a constructor

Comment: Okay, I get an instance of SQLMembershipProvider in my services, but with null implementation. Do I need to Initialize it by adding another variable for example: `var abc = new SqlMembershipProvider();
 abc.Initialize();`?

Comment: If I were you, I would use .net core app.config file to implement the settings

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that:

Firstly, define classes to handle appsettings.json

```
public class MembershipSettings{
    public string DefaultProvider { get; set; }
    public Provider Provider { get; set; }
}

public class Provider
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionStringName { get; set; } //not sure if it works
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    //etc
}
```

Then inherit from SqlMembershipProvider

```
internal class CustomeSqlMembershipProvider : SqlMembershipProvider
{
    public CustomeSqlMembershipProvider(IOptions<MembershipSettings> settings)
    {
        InitializeProvider(settings.Value);
    }

    protected virtual void InitializeProvider(MembershipSettings settings)
    {
        base.Initialize(settings.Provider.Name, PrepareSettings(settings.Provider));
    }

    private NameValueCollection PrepareSettings(Provider provider) => new NameValueCollection
    {
        //you can use reflection to do that as well

        { nameof(provider.ApplicationName), provider.ApplicationName},
        {nameof(provider.ConnectionStringName), provider.ConnectionStringName}

        //...
        //etc
    };
}
```

And in the Startup.cs add following lines:

```
services.Configure<MembershipSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("Membership"));
services.AddScoped<SqlMembershipProvider, CustomSqlMembershipProvider>();
```

And last but not least, modify your appsettings.json a little (you can adjust MembershiSettings class and CustomSqlMembershiProvider to handle and initialize list of providers)

```
"Membership": {
    "DefaultProvider": "blahblah",
    "Provider": {
        ...
        "Name": "blahblah"
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that I'm not so familiar with SqlMembershipProvider so there could be some flaws. In my opinion you should write your own MembershipProvider but if you can't (because of legacy code) then you can do something as above